# A GapHelper static class to create unique (non-existing) size restricted names

Tags: c#, iterator, generator

I am working with a 3th party library which has following interface defined for a processing task:

```
public interface IProcessor {
    void Execute( FileContent fileContent );
}
```

Such an `IProcessor` gives me the possibility to change the `FileContent` before it gets written to the database. For legacy reasons, and for integration reasons with an unnamed ERP, its unique identifiers are string identifiers which have a limitation in length, and they are padded on the left with padding char `'0'`.

Names will therefore always have the form of `00100` or `02301` or `10179` for a 5 digit identifier.

Sometimes, we need to add new content inside the `fileContent.Components`, but we are not allowed to change the existing identifiers. Theoretically any number of items could be added to the components, but for the question at hand, I simplified it to just adding 20 items.

The existing identifiers do not have any order to them, nor can I be sure that the highest number inside the string would be lower than the theoretical maximum number for this identifier.

To handle this addition, I thought I could use a `IEnumerator<string>` function (not class) as an iterator, that creates the next number starting from the theoretical minimum value to the theoretical maximum value, and throw when it exceeds the maximum value.

```
public static class GapHelper {
    public static IEnumerator<string> GetNextName( int maxSize, IEnumerable<string> items, Func<int, string> transform ) {
        var maxLength = (long)Math.Pow( maxSize, 10 );
        var hashSet = new HashSet<string>( items );
        for (var i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
            var text = transform(i);
            if (hashSet.Contains( text )) {
                continue;
            }
            yield return text;
        }
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( "Iteration exceeded maximum numbers of items at " + maxSize );
    }

    public static IEnumerator<string> GetNextName( int maxSize, IEnumerable<string> items) {
        return GetNextName( maxSize, items, i => i.ToString().PadLeft( maxSize, '0' ) );
    }
}
```

and this would be used inside such an `IProcessor` in the following way:

```
public class ProcessingTask : IProcessor {
    public void Execute( FileContent fileContent ) {
        using (var nameGenerator = GapHelper.GetNextName( 5, fileContent.Components.Select( c => c.Name ) ) ) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                nameGenerator.MoveNext();
                fileContent.Components.Add( new Component { 
                    Name = nameGenerator.Current, Content = "Foo"
                } );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I cannot change:

- How the processor is called, and with which parameters
- How the file is processed afterwards, and might have been processed before
- My bracket positioning, we have them at the end of each line
- I am aware I didn't add documentation to the methods

A full simplified example can be found in [this dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HyTQmK).

I am interested in how this code looks from maintainability perspective, and what other potential options I might have overlooked. I am also curious if having an `IEnumerator<string>` implemented as a method rather than a class makes a big difference, either for this implementation or from an iterator perspective.

Comment: I vote to close this question because of this: _Theoretically any number of items could be added to the components, but for the question at hand, I simplified it to just adding 20 items._ - it makes it difficult to figure out whether the result **must** have `n` number of items or **can** have. In other words do you add _fake_ items to the result as you are doing here or do you stop when there are no more items to add.

Comment: @t3chb0t That's a good point, it was hard to know how much I could simply the question without oversimplifying the process. It is indeed a bit more complex as the number of items I would add is undefined at compilation time, I get it from another file, and there are 3 dependent counters on top of it, one for subitems of the component, and two for the component. I chose not to do it that complex for the questions, but maybe I should

Comment: Do you have any tests for this code?  It helps reviewers to be able to build and run the code, and experiment with it.

Comment: @TobySpeight well I did add a link to a dotnetfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Possible Bug

Since `Func<int, string> transform` is not guarded against collisions (different `int` values may yield the same string `result`), the next line is wrong. It only checks for unique elements in the already available data `items`, not in the new results fetched from `transform`.

> ```
>  if (hashSet.Contains( text )) {
> ```

This could be solved by trying to add each element to the set instead:

```
if (!hashSet.Add( text )) {
```

### LINQ

Furthermore, I would use an `IEnumerable` to allow for some LINQ chaining.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetNextName(
  int maxSize, IEnumerable<string> items, Func<int, string> transform) {
```

So we could just call:

```
public class ProcessingTask : IProcessor {
    public void Execute( FileContent fileContent ) {
        GapHelper.GetNextName(5, fileContent.Components
            .Select(c => c.Name)).Take(20).Select(x 
                => new Component { Name = x, Content = "Foo" })
            .ToList().ForEach(fileContent.Components.Add);
    }
}
```

Which yields better readability. Also a fun fact about [disposing an enumerator](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kcwalina/2005/01/07/the-reason-why-ienumerator-extens-idisposable/) from the initial code:

> ```
>  using (var nameGenerator = // ..
> ```

Comment: Ha, good one on the bug, I had actually refactored that for the question, but didn't test it with anything else ^_^ before that the padding was done in the method, but it didn't feel right :) On the topic of chaining, that would be nice, but I am iterating an external file given to me (I know that the question didn't reflect that, so sorry), and I will have 3 different iterators there

Comment: I only don't get the comment on disposing an enumerator, I honestly don't mind it, it makes sense to have it disposed since I will probably never really iterate the full list, so having it in a using feels like second nature to me, as it implements the `IDisposable`

Comment: Eric Lippert suggests not to bother with disposing enumerators, since its only purpose is to for some interop. But it can't hurt ether if you keep using it.

Comment: mhmm... have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21337552/235671) post of him? He says the opposite: _**Always dispose your enumerators.** They implement `IDisposable` for a reason._ which the linked article confirms.

Comment: @t3chb0t He has a more recent post where he argued otherwise.